# Hide / Remove columns when exporting to PDF document using iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net, itext

I have a GridView with data. Some of the columns in my Gridview are hidden `visible=false` .

I am trying to export the GridView to a PDF document using iTextSharp but the columns that are set to `visible=false` are also showing in my PDF document and I don't want that.

How can I export my GridView data to a PDF document without the hidden columns?

This is what I've done so far:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(gvSchedule.HeaderRow.Cells.Count);
    foreach (GridViewRow gridViewRow in gvSchedule.Rows)
    {
        gvSchedule.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        gvSchedule.Columns[1].Visible = false;
        foreach (TableCell tableCell in gridViewRow.Cells)
        {
            gvSchedule.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            gvSchedule.Columns[1].Visible = false;

            PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(tableCell.Text));
            pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell);
        }
    }
    Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, Response.OutputStream);

    pdfDocument.Open();
    pdfDocument.Add(pdfTable);
    pdfDocument.Close();

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=mySchedule.pdf");
    Response.Write(pdfDocument);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

The two columns that I DO NOT want to display on my PDF document are:

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" visible="false" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address"/>

 <asp:BoundField DataField="Area" visible="false" HeaderText="Area" SortExpression="Area"/>
```

Comment: Looks like an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/48465254/766786

Answer (score 1):

Am not familiar with iTextSharp

But looking at your code

```
//enter condition here to not add the row 
         foreach (TableCell tableCell in gridViewRow.Cells)
        {
            gvSchedule.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            gvSchedule.Columns[1].Visible = false;
          if(not visiblity false)
          {
            PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(tableCell.Text));
            pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell);
           } 
        }
```

That way based on visiblity you can avoid creating that column for  all the rows

Hope this helps !

Comment: I got my if statement to do something now at least however I am still struggling to find the logic in my else condition

               ` if (gvSchedule.Columns[0].Visible != false)
                {
                    PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(tableCell.Text));
                    pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell);
                }
                else
                {
                    //unsure what to do in my else statement
                }`

Comment: I dont think you need anything in else because only thing we need is to hide the columns. No else right ?